# Possible memory corruption cause by TMessageManager.SubscribeToMessage

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Debugging a rare issue in my application I have noticed that sometimes
`TCanvasDestroyListenerProxy.CanvasDestroyListener` has corrupted `FTextLayout` pointer.

I'm not quite sure that I found correctly the crux of the matter, so I'm asking if the reasoning below makes sense.

First, each `TCanvas.FillText` causes Subscribe and Immediately UnSubscribe to 2 messages.

Looking at how `SubscribeToMessage` works, we see that it use monotonously increasing `FLastId: Integer;`

In an application that draws a lot of graphics with `FillText` output, the `FLastId` will overflow soon, so that its possible that new `L: TListenerWithId` will get the same `L.ID` as already existing in the `Subscribers` list. And later a wrong instance of `TCanvasDestroyListenerProxy` will be freed.

Does this assumption make sense? Unfortunately I haven't managed to create a test example for such case. Overflowing `FLastId` is easy, but having 2 same IDs are much rare case.

Also, there is a question, is it possible to get rid of 2 consecutive operations (Subscribe\UnSubscribe) in `TCanvas.FillText` ?

Comment: File a bug report in Quality Portal https://quality.embarcadero.com/

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar sure I will do but the question for now is about better way to fix it

Comment: It is hard to tell what would be appropriate solution without digging deep into FMX. Most likely solution would be caching the instance that calls Subscribe/Unsubscribe messages so it is reused instead constructed/destructed every time.